# Broken pipe error on Java SSLSocket server with AJAX request

Tags: java, ajax, sockets, ssl, broken-pipe

I have a JAVA server receiving simple requests from the browser. These requests are just GET requests containing a HTML content that will be transformed into a PDF file on the server. After creating the PDF file, the server is supposed to send it back to the client. The client request is an AJAX request.

I got a problem while sending back the file to the client. Actually, the file is correctly created on the server side, but when I try to send it to the client, a broken pipe error occurs. It doesn't appear to do it with very small files, but every time with files around 1MB.

I know that the broken pipe error occurs because the client close the connection while the server is always writing on the socket. But I don't understand why the client close the connection. I don't do any action on the client side, I'm just waiting for the response, but the connection is always closed at the same moment.

My server communicates with the client through SSLSocket, and I'm sending the correct Content-Length in the headers of my response.

Do someone have any idea about why the client is suddenly closing the connection? I can provide more information if needed as well as some portions of my server code.

**Client side AJAX request :**

```
$.ajax({
    url: url_server,
    type: "GET",
    data: param_server,
    dataType: "html",
    statusCode: {
        404: function () {}
    }
});
```

Comment: how is your client side code looks like?

Comment: @AmidalaSivaKumar I edited my post to show the AJAX request. It's a very basic request, and I also tried with timeout 0 in options, but nothing changed.

Comment: do you see any kind of timeout error in console?

Comment: No, it just stop while waiting for the response. In Firefox console I can see the beginning of the response, but in Chrome console nothing appears. As I said, even with no timeout set in the AJAX request, it close the connection.

Comment: While I give a try in chrome, I see there is request cancelled in networks tab if timeout is less than processing time at server side. I have made the thread to sleep for 5 seconds in server side and set timeout to 3 seconds in client side, but while I try with not specifying timeout, the ajax request went through though server side processing took 1 minute too. But server is running on http